# Null reference '#as(test, 0)' that comes from line 28 will be dereferenced at line 28

Tags: c#, klocwork

I have below classes,

```
public class Test1
{
    public Test2 Test2 { get; set; }
}

public class Test2 { }
```

Now I have below method,

```
private void Test()
    {
        var test = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Test");

        if (test != null)
        {
            var a= (test as Test1).Test2;
        }
    }
```

Now I am getting Klockwork error saying,

`Null reference '#as(test, 0)' that comes from line 28 will be dereferenced at line 28`

What this error mean and how to resolve it?

**Note** that this is Klockwork error, however C# compiling will not have any error.

Error at below line of code,

`var a= (test as Test1).Test2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will compile but theres a chance with `as` that the resulting value could be null. You can ensure that it won't throw this way:

```
    var test = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Test") as Test1;

    if (test != null)
    {
        var a = test.Test2;
    }
```